# How to turn a series of letters to hex of a certain form

Tags: python

I am trying to convert say the string `"hi"` into a hexadecimal representation that looks like this:

```
b'\x68\x96'
```

where `x68` is `"h"` and `x96` is `"i"`

One thing I tried is :

```
s = "P".encode('utf-8').hex()
result = bytes(s, 'utf-8)
```

and result is `b'50'`, however this is still not what I need because I need `b'\x50'`. What can I do to put the `\` in result? I've tried a number of things but can't seem to get it to work. My most likely solution has been to extract the `50` from `b'50'` and then append it to a `b= '\x'` But no luck there.

The other solution i've tried is

```
numbers = [1,2,3]
byte_array = bytearray(numbers)
```

and Python terminal outputs :
`bytearray(b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05')`, but the problem here is that I can't input strings here.

Finally i've tried

```
frame = bytearray()
frame.append(0x33)
frame.append(0x01)
```

which outputs `bytearray(b'3\x01')` which is neither here or there.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Correction: `i` is U+69, not U+96

Comment: What do you need this for? It looks like you're doing code generation, but why do you need the bytes literals to be all-escaped?

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in that will do this. All the methods that format byte strings will show printable bytes as the corresponding character, not a`\x` code.

Comment: You can use `byte_array.hex()` to see it as hex codes, but it doesn't have the `\x` prefix. You could insert that before every 2 characters.

Comment: `b'hi' == b'\x68\x69'` is `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you're never going to get a `bytes` object represented like that, but it looks like you're doing code generation, so what you really want is a string that contains a `bytes` representation, like `"b'\\x68\\x69'"` for `hi`.

So, you're on the right track with `.encode(...).hex()`. You just need to insert the `\x` before each byte, for example:

```
s = "café"
hexes_esc = ['\\x'+bytes([b]).hex() for b in s.encode('utf-8')]
bytes_repr_esc = f"b'{''.join(hexes_esc)}'"
print(bytes_repr_esc)  # -> b'\x63\x61\x66\xc3\xa9'
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of works apart from there being two \ between numbers in the result, but I haven't found a way around that.

```
text = 'hi'
result = f''
for i in text:
    hex_text = i.encode('utf_8').hex()
    result = result + rf"\x{hex_text}"
print(result.encode('utf_8'))
```

Output

```
b'\\x68\\x69'
```

Comment: This arguably fails for multi-byte encodings. For example, with `text = 'é'`, the output is `b'\\xc3a9'`, but it should probably be `b'\\xc3\\xa9'`. I had the same problem but fixed it in [my answer](/a/71889369/4518341).

Answer (score 0):

`byte_array.hex()` will return the hex codes you want, but without the `\x` prefixes. You can add them yourself.

```
frame = bytearray()
frame.append(0x33)
frame.append(0x01)
hexcodes = frame.hex()
result = "b'" + ''.join(r'\x' + hexcodes[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hexcodes), 2)) + "'"
print(result)  # -> b'\x33\x01'
```